# find local minimum and maximum of implicit function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem

I know that there are more similar questions and I used them in order to try to solve this question.

But I can't figure out how to continue please help me.

here is the question

> the following equation $y^2 + 2x\cdot y = 2x - 4x^2 $ defines a function $y(x)$. Find and sort the function's critical points

Now I did the following using implicit differentiation  :

$$F = y^2 + 2x\cdot y - 2x + 4x^2 =0 $$
$$\frac{dy}{dx} =\frac{-F_x}{F_y} =\frac{-(2y-2+8x)}{2y+2x}$$
$$-(2y-2+8x)=0 \Rightarrow y=-4x+1$$
and now I cant figure out how to continue -

As far as I understand any point that is on $y=-4x+1$ is a critical point, but how can I determine whether it is a local min, max or none?

Further more:
By the implicit function theorem **for each** solution $(x_0, y_0)$ for the provided equation there is a single function $y(x)$  (assuming $F'y(x_0, y_0)\neq 0$ ) but in the question above I somehow supposed to find one function it doesn't make sense to me...

what am I doing wrong?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

Here you already have $y = -4x+1$, just plug the $y = y(x)$ back in the original $y^2 + 2xy = 2x - 4x^2$ and solve for $x$.

There might be zero or two real solutions to $x$. If there are two (including a single solution with multiplicity of $2$), those are the points on the curve.

These are the critical points defined by having an asymptote **OR** tangent line in some direction, including horizontal. (what you did was effectively letting $\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$ via setting $F_x = 0$)

If there is no real solution, see the next section after the dividor.

Next you should do the same by setting $F_y = 0$, which might give you another set of critical points defined by asymptote or tangent line (perhaps vertical).

It is a standard procedure and you should check both $F_x =0$ and $F_y = 0$. You can get some accurate information without making a precise plot.

When the points satisfy both $F_x = 0$ and $F_y = 0$, then $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac00$ is undetermined (by that formula you use), which means the asymptote (or tangent line) defining the critical point is neither horizontal nor vertical.

---

The given equation is a quadratic curve (a.k.a. conic section) that is either an ellipse (including circle), a parabola, or a hyperbola (a pair of arcs).

There's a standard way to categorize a quadratic equation via its discriminant with precal methods. [See wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#General_Cartesian_form) or [Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticCurve.html).

Note that a general parabola has one tangent line with a single critical point which $x$ is a single root with multiplicity of $2$.

If it's an ellipse (which happens to be the case here), there are always 4 such critical points on the curve to let you "sort" as per the requirement.

A hyperbola always have $4$ such critical points "at the infinity" defined by the asymptotes. This is the case where there is no real solution when you plug $y = y(x)$ back.

Answer (score 0):

$$
y^2 + 2 x y = 2 x - 4 x^2\to y^2+4x^2+2x y-2x=0
$$

which is an ellipse so the maximum and minimum are determined at the tangent points between

$$
y^2+4x^2+2x y-2x=0\\
y=\lambda
$$

or

$$
\lambda^2+4x^2+2x\lambda-2x=0
$$

or solving for $x$

$$
x = \frac 14\left(1-\lambda\pm\sqrt{1-2\lambda-2\lambda^2}\right)
$$

but tangency implies on

$$
1-2\lambda-2\lambda^2 = 0\to\lambda = \{-1,\frac 13\}
$$

[image]